# Build error with UILocalNotification with older deployment target in XCode 4

Tags: xcode, deployment, build, uilocalnotification

I have a project I am trying to build with XCode 4.1 that built fine on 3.2.5. The base sdk is set to 4.3 and the deployment target is set to 3.2. I've reproduced the problem in a simple project with the following code:

```
    Class notificationClass = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");

    // Make sure local notifications are supported
    if (notificationClass)
    {
        UILocalNotification *taskNotice = [[notificationClass alloc] init];
        [taskNotice release];
    }
```

On the UILocalNotification line I get the error: 'UILocalNotification' undeclared (first use in this function)

The relevant settings are:
Compiler: LLVM GCC 4.2 (also tried Apple LLVM compiler 2.1)
Weak-linked: UIKit, Foundation, CoreGraphics

I've scoured Google and Apple's docs and tried everything I could find with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: Quick note: Changing Targeted Device Family to iPad makes the problem go away. It's an iPhone app though so this doesn't help.

Comment: Looks like the problem was due to the iOS Deployment Target being set to 3.2. Setting it to 3.2.1 made the problem go away. I can live with that. I can't answer the question yet due to my reputation being too low so I have to wait 5 more hours. I'll answer it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears that the problem was because I had the iOS Deployment Target set to 3.2. I've set it to 3.2.1 and now it builds fine. May be due to 3.2 being iPad only but the same thing happened on the iPad version of the app so I'm not sure.
Jason